# Navigation in UWP app causes memory leak

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I have a root page which contains a `SplitView` and it contains a `rootFrame`. I show my app's pages in this frame.

```
<SplitView DisplayMode="Overlay">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <Grid/>
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <Frame x:Name="rootFrame"/>
</SplitView>
```

I navigate from one page to another with this code

```
myRootPage.rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MySecondPage));
```

The problem is that after a few navigation back and forth memory usage increases and finally app crashes!

using Memory Profiler in Visual Studio, I noticed the huge increase happens after navigating back. but I don't know where should I look in the report to see what causes that.

How to avoid this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: oh bad news! It's because of Microsoft Ad SDK !

Answer (score 0):

Set `NavigationCacheMode` to `NavigationCacheMode.Required` so the app will not create a new instance of your page every time you navigate to it but only for the first time:

```
<Page <!-- some unrelated XAML code -->
      NavigationCacheMode="Required"
      >
```